# Databinding single source to multiple ComboBox'es not updating all of them

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

Let's say I have four comboboxes (let's call the cbA1, cbA2, cbB1, cbB2), cbA1 and cbB1 are bound to the same property and cbA2 and cbB2 to a different property in my viewmodel. Before I switched over to MVVM I had some codebehind that made sure the same value wasn't the same in cbA1 and cbB1. They use an enum as the itemssource.

You'll have to ignore the reasons why I have this many comboboxes displaying the data as it is for now. I only stumbled on this accidentally.

This is how they are constructed in XAML:

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name"cbA1"
    DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
    SelectedValuePath="Value" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Window1Page}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local:Enumeration {x:Type Enum:eDisplayPages}}}"/>  
<ComboBox 
    x:Name"cbA2"
    DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
    SelectedValuePath="Value" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Window2Page}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local:Enumeration {x:Type Enum:eDisplayPages}}}"/>
```

So when I run the app the #1 comboboxes display the data from Window1Page and the #2 comboboxes display the data from Window2Page. My old codebehind checked to make sure that what was in the #1 comboboxes couldn't be in #2 comboboxes. This worked a treat. Now I'm moving to the MVVM model I've moved the code to do the check into the property itself. Here is one of the properties:

```
    public eDisplayPages Window1Page
    {
        get { return _window1page; }
        set
        {
            if (_window1page == value)
                return;

            if ((value.Equals(_window2page)) && (value != eDisplayPages.NoDashPage))
            {
                //Can't have them both selecting the same page
                value = eDisplayPages.NoDashPage;
            }

            SetProperty(ref _window1page, value);
        }
    }
```

Although not really pertinent here is the enum to help you visualise the issue:

```
public enum eDisplayPages
{
    [Description("NO Layout")]
    NoDashPage = 0,
    [Description("Main Layout")]
    MainDashPage,
    [Description("Timing Layout")]
    TimingOnlyDashPage
}
```

So the issue I'm seeing is that when I change lets say cbA1 to the same value as cbA2 the property code runs and changes the value to the default "NoDashPage", but it only updates the combobox that I didn't make the change in, in this case cbB1.

The old codebehind method used to change the combobox I was focused on as well as the other combobox. The only difference there was that I used to set the SelectedValue of the focused combobox to the new value, which did update the other combobox.

I don't understand why it doesn't then change the combobox I made the initial selection in. If I go into the debugger the value of Window1Page is correct.

Whilst I'll eventually remove the duplicate comboboxes the fact the one I have focus on isn't updating is the biggest issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement looks unnatural to my eyes, why do you change the (reserved) `value` variable?

```
public eDisplayPages Window1Page
{
    get { return _window1page; }
    set
    {
        if (_window1page == value)
            return;

        if ((value.Equals(_window2page)) && (value != eDisplayPages.NoDashPage))
        {
            //Can't have them both selecting the same page
            _window1page = eDisplayPages.NoDashPage;
        }
        else
        {
            _window1page = value;
        }
        //TODO: add some change notification here
    }
}
```